# How to prevent white cells in css-grid

Tags: css

```css
.wrapper{
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 950px;
  display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 29.2rem;
    grid-auto-rows: 29.2rem;
    grid-gap: 3rem;
}
.item{
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
}
.item.large{
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 2
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="item">item</div>
<div class="item large">item</div>
<div class="item">item</div>
<div class="item">item</div>
<div class="item">item</div>
<div class="item">item</div>
<div class="item">item</div>
<div class="item">item</div>
<div class="item">item</div>
<div class="item">item</div>
<div class="item">item</div>
<div class="item">item</div>
<div class="item">item</div>
<div class="item">item</div>
<div class="item large">item</div>
<div class="item">item</div>
</div>
```

hello, please is there a way i can prevent the grid system from having empty cell automatically no matter the amount of rows i create? in this example there is an empty cell before the 15th item

Comment: Are referring to the gap?

Comment: no the empty space at the row before the last row

Comment: Are you referring to the 50px margin on your wrapper?

Comment: no, the empty cell between the 14th and the 15th or 16th item just before the last large item,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you may be looking for is:

`grid-auto-flow: dense;`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow

You can also pair this styling with `row` or `column` depending on what you need specifically

```css
.wrapper{
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 950px;
  display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 29.2rem;
    grid-auto-rows: 29.2rem;
    grid-gap: 3rem;
    grid-auto-flow: dense;
}
.item{
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
}
.item.large{
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 2
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="item">item</div>
<div class="item large">item</div>
<div class="item">item</div>
<div class="item">item</div>
<div class="item">item</div>
<div class="item">item</div>
<div class="item">item</div>
<div class="item">item</div>
<div class="item">item</div>
<div class="item">item</div>
<div class="item">item</div>
<div class="item">item</div>
<div class="item">item</div>
<div class="item">item</div>
<div class="item large">item</div>
<div class="item">item</div>
</div>
```